# Prevent ui-resizable handles from automatically triggering overflow scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hi I use jqueryui/resizable for a `<div id="blue">` element that contains a child`<div id="red">` with some inner html text content. The blue is `$(".resizable").resizable();` and I want that scrollbars appear if I resize blue smaller than the content of red.

The problem is that because of the classes `.ui-resizable-s .ui-resizable-e` the scrollbars are always visible.

Just look at this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/662tyqv8/4/

If I now hide the horizontal and vertical handles in the JSFiddle, it works ( the overflow scrollbars are only there if needed.

If I look at the DOM Tree, I understand why the scrollbars are always visible:

```
<div id="blue" class="resizable ui-resizable">
    <div id="red">C<br>O<br>N<br>T<br>E<br>X<br>T</div>

    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
</div>
```

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qzY1.jpg) shows that the horizontal handle is outside of the area of the blue `<div>` and therefore it automatically adds the scroll bar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say, 'I want to have the handle and scrollbars only if I really hide some context of red' does not make sense to me.

Comment: Hi, I changed the question, I want that the `ui-resizable handles` do not automatically trigger the overflow scrollbars

Comment: You are required to show a minimal code example containing the problem here, not a third-party site which may change or disappear tomorrow, helping no one in the future.

Comment: remove overflow:auto from css in jsfiddle.... it removed the scrollbars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in `resize` where you compare the height of the two elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mf52vhe5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="blue" class=" resizable">
  <div id="red">
    C
    <br>O
    <br>N
    <br>T
    <br>E
    <br>X
    <br>T
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(function() {
   $(".resizable").resizable({
     resize: function(e, ui) {
       var blue = $("#blue");
       var red = $("#red");
       if (blue.height() < red.height()) {
         blue.css("overflow-y", "auto");
       } else {
         blue.css("overflow-y", "hidden");
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

You can also do this by add/removing a class or toggling a class.

```
.scrolling {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Then do this when comparing:

```
if (blue.height() < red.height()) {
    blue.addClass("scrolling");
} else {
    blue.removeClass("scrolling");
}
```